# Cannot upload large file by apache java

Tags: java, apache, multipartform-data

I use `MultipartEntityBuilder` to upload a file. By just changing the file path, I succeeded in uploading a `.txt` file but I couldn't upload a `.bin` file. When invesgating in Wireshark, I couldn't even see the POST request for `.bin`.

Here are the key codes:

```
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(httpURL);
request.addHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
request.addHeader("Accept", "multipart/form-data");

File file = new File(filePath);
FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file, ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
multipartEntityBuilder.addPart("upgradeFile", fileBody);
multipartEntityBuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
HttpEntity httpEntity = multipartEntityBuilder.build();

request.setEntity(httpEntity);
CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
```

Also, I tried modifying `ContentType` to such as `application/octet-stream` but it didn't work. Would anyone have some solution? Thank a ton.

**Update**

As I verified, the problem is not the type of file but the size of file. I tried a 6Mb binary file, a 37Mb binary file and a 60Mb binary file, only the smallest could be uploaded.

In fact, my program is like a simulator of a website. In the real website, I did can upload a large file but I don't understand why I cannot in my program.

Comment: Most web servers have a configurable maximum size limit for uploads...

Comment: @Robert Yes you are right. But as I mentioned, I can upload a large file from the website. However I cannot upload the same file in my program.

Comment: I do face the same problem with png files